# AVFoundation recording date/time stamp in video file

Tags: ios, xcode, avfoundation

I am trying to make the following: Using AVFoundation to record a video on iPhone and merge the video with a date/time stamp (and maybe other important information). I have the recording working and output is fine. I have also added to the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer and see the preview. To the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer I have added a CATextLayer which is updated with NSTimer - all this works fine. BUT, the CATextLayer is not recorded in the output.mov file.

Does anyone has done something similar or have an idea how to merge the output.mov with the CATextLayer. The idea is that when later watching the output.mov, the user should see the date and time (and maybe other important information) when the video was taken.

Answer (score 3):

You're just showing the text on top of the preview. You'd need to actually mix the text into the image buffer before encoding. So you'd use an AVCaptureOutput to get the video data into a callback in your app. Then you'd need to draw on the pixel buffer and finally pass the mixed buffer to an AVAssetWriterInput for encoding and file writing.